# TFS 2012 work item ui window refresh

Tags: c#, event-handling

I've created Server side Event Handler on TFS 2012 Server. After saving work item, i put some logic, what calculate data from few fields and show in another one. The problem is, that after saving work item element ( by clik 'save' button ), i've havent my changes - becous they begin to calculate only AFTER saving, and i want to refresh UI Window with Work Item, but not know how to. Any suggestions?

P.S. In Visual Studio and in Web Access.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not possible, at least directly from TFS API. You will have to create your on plugin for Team Explorer and Web Access.